# magento2 problem with sessions

Tags: magento2, sessions

I have problem with session_start()

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php on line 191 in /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'session_start()...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 191, Array)\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(191): session_start()\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(167): Magento\\Framework\\Session\\SessionManager->start()\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(127): Magento\\Backend\\Model\\Auth\\Session\\Interceptor->start()\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/my-domains.com\n', referer: https://my-domains.com/setup/
```

Comment: Where do you store your session either in db or files? Are you using Memcached or any other? What is your Magento version?

Comment: i have magento version 2.3.0.
I save my session in files

Comment: Can you please check var folder permission and ownership?

Comment: i have permission for root to var/lib/php/session. but I have another user for magento2

Comment: Can you please check magento_root/var/session has proper permissions?

Comment: i don't have folder var/session on my magento2.3.0 or did i misunderstand you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91915/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-denis-maksiura).

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the **memory_limit** and the **session lifetime** to get this error out. Since you are using plesk make sure to change those values in the correct place.